# Multiply Without The Operator '*' - float EXTENDED

Tags: c

How can I do multiply two numbers without the '*' or '/' operator

**It's different from the other question because I need *float* too**

I need to consider negative with positive, real with fraction, every possibility of multiply

I have an Idea that I will do the real number first (5, 3, 8 and etc...) and then the fraction(0.5, 0.33333, and etc...)

`float fraction = (float)x - (int)x; // I can calculate the fraction with this`

I think I can "multiply" the fraction to be int and then do the multiply with real numbers but the problem is how I return it back how it was (divide by ten without divide)

With this (do this function until the number return is bigger then 0):

```
float multiBy10(float a)
{
    float backup = a;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++, a += backup);
    return a;
}
```

I saw this [here](http://www.hackersdelight.org/divcMore.pdf) but it with int and bit manipulation don't work on float number

```
int divs10(int n)
{
    int q, r;
    n = n + (n>>31 & 9);
    q = (n >> 1) + (n >> 2);
    q = q + (q >> 4);
    q = q + (q >> 8);
    q = q + (q >> 16);
    q = q >> 3;
    r = n - q*10;
    return q + ((r + 6) >> 4);
    // return q + (r > 9);
}
```

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++, a += backup);` you're getting floating point accumulation error. I'd say work on the IEEE representation of the float (mantissa+exponent). there you can use bitshift.

Comment: May I ask why you need it?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre can you give example

Comment: @Programmmer_Z I would never have guessed:)  Only in academia would they ask you to drive a nail without using a hammer.

Comment: Such questions are not useful to future users/visitors:(

Comment: @Programmmer_Z that's not trivial. I know the principle but I wouldn't dare try to code it...

Comment: @klutt collage assignment*

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre where can I know the principle too?

Comment: @MartinJames collage, not school, my mistake

Comment: @Programmmer_Z start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic

Comment: Multiply is easy. Divide is trickier. In both cases, start with the fact that a FP number is a mantissa multiplied two to the power of an exponent. To multiply, multiply the mantissas; add the exponents; renormalize.